# I can't restart the ssh (git bash)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I changed some settings about ssh in git bash.
And I tried 'service ssh restart' command. But I failed.

I don't know my password, so I just enter the password.
So fist time, I thought that PW made this problem. But other people says originally pw is none.

Is is the pw problem? or else?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication failure generally indicates that your current account has insufficient privileges. These problems can generally be solved by rerunning the command as root, by appending "sudo" to your command. Try running "sudo service ssh restart".

Comment: You mean _prepending_

Answer (score 1):

You need to have root privileges to use the `service` command.

`service` will detect that you are missing privileges and attempt to elevate the privileges for you, but it does so by asking for the password. You are probably using passwordless authentication though, so there is no password that would work here at all.

Instead, you need to use `sudo`. In your case, I'd assume that `sudo` is most likely configured to elevate your privileges *without* requiring a password. This way, `service` will be called with the right privileges in the first place and won't have to ask for any password anymore.

```sh
sudo service ssh restart
```